# how to make a function add on to a string in main without replacing the previous data in string?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make menu options where a function for option a will allow a user to input data into a string. when a is recalled, I can't get new user input into the string without deleting the prior. I tried using concat to just add on to the end of the string but it simply keeps replacing the old text with the new text in the string. below is my main class option a.

```
for(;;)
        {
        menuOptions();
           String[] menuChoice = new String[4];
           menuChoice[0] = choice.next();
           System.out.println("your choice is " + menuChoice[0] + "\n");
        
        if (menuChoice[0].equals("a"))
        {//menu choice a.
            userInput = optionA(_userInput);
        }
```

below is my function for option a.

```
        public static String optionA(String _userInput)
        {
            _userInput = "";
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner for user input.
            System.out.println("Enter new text: ");
            if (_userInput == "") {//checks if string is empty
                _userInput = s.nextLine();
                System.out.println(_userInput);
            } else 
            {
            String newLine = s.nextLine();

            _userInput = _userInput.concat(newLine);
            }//end else
            return _userInput;
```

My second menu option allows the user to see what is stored in the string. right now when I run option a and b twice this is what happens:

```
option a 1st time: enter text: "All the way!"
option b 1st time: search: "All" output - index 0
option a 2nd time: enter text: "Even more!"
option b 2nd time: search: "All" output - index -1
```

so basically after I run the first menu option again it just replaces the string with the new input. How can I get it to just add it on to the end of the string?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. What variable are you updating and in which function?

Comment: what is *_userInput* in main class? *userInput = optionA(_userInput);*

Comment: I'm trying to get optionA to save the input into userInput in the main class.

Comment: @sittsering _userInput is null in main class.

Comment: ok, and each time optionA is called, you want userinput to concat to prior userinput?

Comment: @sittsering yes that is spot on with what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So do this in main class and replace `_userInput` to `userInput`.

```
String userInput  = "";
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
...
if (menuChoice[0].equals("a"))
        {
            userInput = optionA(userInput,s);
        }
```

for optionA

```
public static String optionA(String userInput, Scanner s)
{
      System.out.println("Enter new text: ");
      String newLine = s.nextLine();
      userInput = userInput + newLine;
      return userInput;
}
```

Whether if the string is empty or not, it'll do the same thing.

Comment: I feel like I made this way more difficult than it needed to be, too much overthinking. this worked, thanks!

Comment: @Tom Thanks I didn't know scanners behaved like that: Closing a Scanner closes the underlying stream. Scanners are such an SO staple that I should be better informed...